# ¿Sumatorio de enlaces en bipartite?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-bipartite

Dado el siguiente código de una red bipartita con enlaces pesados:

```
prueba<-read.csv("matriz_prueba.csv",header=TRUE,sep=";")
head(prueba)

  PAIS_ORIGEN     AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM
1         USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19
2          EU  609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17
3         IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73
4         FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29
5         JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79
6         DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22
```

Me gustaría saber si hay alguna función en la librería bipartite que me sume el peso de todos los enlaces de un nodo y me devuelva el sumatorio de esos pesos para cada nodo, tanto en fila como en columna.

Ejemplo: (USA-AFG)+(USA-ETH)+...+(USA-VNM) => USA: 11.484,46

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Lo más simple es usar [`rowSums()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/raster/versions/3.3-13/topics/rowSums), solo hay que descartar las columna `PAIS_ORIGEN`  de la suma:

```
prueba$Total <- rowSums(prueba[,-1])
prueba

  PAIS_ORIGEN     AFG     ETH     TZA     PAK     VNM    Total
1         USA 6686.77 1726.46  834.16 2044.88  192.19 11484.46
2          EU  609.50  396.27  298.63  244.11   84.17  1632.68
3         IDA  424.68 1637.79 1461.09 1150.64 1939.73  6613.93
4         FRA   95.65   45.01   26.00   20.54  341.29   528.49
5         JPN  867.20  154.99  182.21  272.97 1622.79  3100.16
6         DEU  754.42  164.52  207.36  233.14  194.22  1553.66
```

Por cierto, esto no es algo particular de `bipartite`, sino una  solución más general que aplica a cualquier estructura tabular tipo matriz o `data.frame`

Comment: Gracias @PatricioMoracho ! Eso sería una buena solución, aunque lo ideal sería sacarlo a través de alguna función de bipartite.
Existe la función strenght() que debería sumar la fuerza de todos los vertices del nodo, pero el resultado devuelto no es el esperado.